# How do I fix a small bug in Linux Mint 21 Calendar from BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, calendar, linux-mint

OS: Linux Mint 21 Live CD. Not installed.
I open up the terminal and type `date`. The date is **Aug 09** late evening (Chicago timezone).
I open up the calendar on the bottom right and it shows **Aug 10** as the highlighted day.

Here is the Calendar bug in image [image: Calendar Bug]

**I do NOT want to install Linux Mint to get rid of the bug. I want to fix it on Live CD. What bash command(s) can I type into the terminal to fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a locale inconsistency -- that is the panel app that shows the calendar is in a different timezone than the terminal and shell.  Panel apps usually don't feature command line interfaces.  But maybe something like this would work:

1. `kill` either the calendar app or the entire panel it's docked on.
2. From the command line, restart an instance of the panel, or the calendar app, whichever was just `kill`ed.
3. Repeat the test, and see if that fixed it.

Without testing it, I don't know for sure if the above would really work, and I'm also not sure of the name of the processes to `kill` on the Linux Mint CD.  Perhaps some more knowledgeable reader can improve this answer by adding those app names?

Comment: Hey! Thanks! That kinda worked in a way. I did not know what pid name is calendar so I decided to `sudo service lightdm restart` That solved the bug for now but the sideffect is that everything on my screen had to be reopened. Also I do not know if 24 hours from now I will face the same issue...